# C# Excel Trim worksheet cell when passing to a datatable?

Tags: c#

Here is the code below i'm using, how do you trim while doing the convert.ToString()?

```
while (((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)workSheet.Cells[rowIndex, 1]).Value2 != null)
        {
            rowIndex = 2 + index;
            row = excel_Holding_Table.NewRow();
            for (int i = 1; i <= range.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                row[i-1] = Convert.ToString(((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)workSheet.Cells[rowIndex, i]).Value2);
            }
            excel_Holding_Table.Rows.Add(row);
            index++;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the below line..Add the Trim() function at the last

```
row[i-1] = Convert.ToString(((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)workSheet.Cells[rowIndex, i]).Value2);
```

to

```
string temp = Convert.ToString(((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)workSheet.Cells[rowIndex, i]).Value2);
if(temp!=null)
     row[i-1] =temp.Trim();
else
     row[i-1] = "";
```

Comment: That doesn't actually work, you get Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference

Comment: That means Convert.ToString() is returning null...Split the code as mentioned above(I edited my answer)..might work!

Comment: I need to add that row even if its null

Comment: string tmp = Convert.ToString(((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)workSheet.Cells[rowIndex, i]).Value2);
                    if (tmp != null)
                    {
                        row[i - 1] = tmp.Trim();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        row[i - 1] = Convert.ToString(((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)workSheet.Cells[rowIndex, i]).Value2);
                    }